# How to do bulk update of fields for test suite in test link?

Tags: testcase, test-suite, testlink

There is a test suite already created with test summary and test steps in test link. I have to update few fields in each test case. How can i update in bulk instead of doing it one by one by clicking edit option for each test case?

Comment: Can you explain which fields exactly you need to update ? AFAIU you have to update one by one. Or else has to go to db level. I don't see any TestLink provides to handle these kind of situation

Comment: it can be custom field or any flag like execution type... One workaround i found is export the test suite as XML and update the XML n import back the same again. I wish i could update them from UI in bulk.

Comment: Yea, Agree. That will be a practical workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can update in bulk some of the fields like Status and Importance by selecting the test suite and click on Settings icon, then the Table view.